# Can't write ${all-event-properties} to File target with NLog

Tags: nlog

I have latest at the moment of writing NLog 5.1.4 and the following config (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
    </extensions>
    <variable name="projectName" value="WebApi" />
    <variable name="environment" value="${appsetting:item=Environment}"/>
    <targets async="true">
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Logs\${projectName}\file.log"
                layout="${date} | ${level} | ${message} | ${all-event-properties}" />
        <target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
            <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
                    includeAllProperties="true"
                    index="${environment}-${lowercase:${projectName}}-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}"
                    uri="http://localhost:9200"
                    layout="${message}">
            </target>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file,elastic"/>   
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I use Fluent API to write properties to the log and **I can see** them in elastic, but for some reasons I can't see them in file. Only spaces are rendered after delimiter. I also tried to print properties separately with same results. Internal logging show no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of how your capture the LogEvent-properties, along with example of property-class-types ?

Answer (score 1):

Case closed, I'm stupid, sorry for wasting your time  We put logs to a different files based on ${callsite} and all structured part went not to the file a was looking in.